# How to validate my controller action was called from within my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, validation

I have a simple user registration form.

When the user fills out the form and clicks "Submit" I have a JavaScript event that intercepts the submit and uses AJAX to call the `validate` method below to check the form data before submitting. If the form data is ok it continues with the submit, but if it's not it cancels the Submit and displays a warning on the page. It's a simple way of doing real-time client side validations.

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb

# Validates the form data. Returns an error message response in the format
#   { response: "Invalid email format!" }
#
# A blank response means success
#
def validate
  if request.xhr? || <request came from another method in this controller>
    # Run various validations on input data and determine a response
    # response_text = ...
    render json: { response: response_text }
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end

def create
  if JSON.parse(validate)["response"].blank?
    User.create(...)
    # Other stuff
  end
end
```

However when the submit does eventually pass and go through, it sends a `POST` to the `create` action to create a new `User`. That method calls `validate` *again* (the cost of re-validating is minimal) to ensure that no one bypassed the form and submitted a malicious request directly to the server.

So my `validate` method has to respond to both (a) AJAX calls and (b) "internal" calls from within the app. All other calls to the validate action should just redirect to the root path.

I can tell whether the call was an a AJAX call pretty simple using `request.xhr?`.

1. How do I check whether the action was called internally and not by a user?
2. Taking a step back, is this a good general approach for validation? Any thoughts to improve on it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Rails generates an [authenticity token](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html) whenever a user views a form and stores it as a random string in the HTML. That token is also stored in the session and is therefore invisible to the user. Upon receiving a request, your application will compare the tokens to verify whether the request was generated from your form.

TL;DR: Don't worry, you're already protected.

Comment: That's good to know - but in this case I can directly bypass the form and `POST` a request to my app, which goes to `create`. It will try to call `validate` as shown, but since it isn't an AJAX request the `validate` method wont even validate anything. I could remove that requirement of `if request.xhr?` but I wanted to see if there was a way to explicitly whitelist what's calling this method, since it's also accessible to a user via a public route

Comment: @user2490003 I suppose that's what was confusing to me about your requirements. If you already have protection against CSRF, then is your client side validation giving you any utility? Is explicit control really necessary?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a specific answer, but *do* have some information which could help. I'll gladly delete this if required...

---

> AJAX calls and "internal" calls

You have to understand that XHR requests can *only* come from your app -- [CORS (cross origin resource sharing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Ajax calls can only come from your own domain, so don't think a malicious hacker could run some scraper or whatever -- [you choose](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) which domains are permitted to send XHR requests.

So when you're calling...

```
if request.xhr?
```

... as part of a validation, you need to scope when XHR will be used.

---

On the same note, what validation are you performing?

If you're validating input data, Rails handles this at the model layer. We've done [something similar](http://firststopcosmeticshop.herokuapp.com) (click login/register at top):

[image]

The base structure of Rails is [`MVC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), which means that your `controller` is only responsible for taking a request & building the appropriate data objects out of it.

Thus, if you're "validating" an input, what is there to validate apart from the data itself (handled by the model)?

[image]

As `@MarsAtomic` specified, too, Rails uses a CSRF token to provide *some* level of authentication for a form submission.

--

You could easily use the following:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, :json, :html
   def create
      @user = User.new user_params
      respond_with @user.save
   end
end
```

If you then sent the request from your front-end as `json`, you'd get back the created user OR the errors:

```
#app/views/users/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @user, remote: true, format: :json do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field .... %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("ajax:error", "#new_user", function(xhr, status, error) {
    // do stuff with response
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's useful info!

Answer (score 0):

In your create method, you want to return a `@user` if it's not valid (if they skip the ajax validate).

If that's the case, you don't want to do `User.create`, instead, create an instance and try to save it.  If you do all this, you're doing the normal controller action for create and there is no need to call validate internally.

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    # Other stuff
  end
end
```

And, it's not a good practice to create a json response and parse it to see if an object is valid. Instead, either test with valid? or just try to save and get back a true or false.

In other words - keep your validate method separate from your create method.  They'll both rely on `valid?` eventually.